# Python: How can I get the current page’s title as a variable in Flask?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

Say I have this HTML page;

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>I want this as a variable</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

And a Python variable in my app called `x`, how could I make `x` = 'I want this as a variable'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup is great for this:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = """
<html>
    <head>
        <title>I want this as a variable</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

x = soup.title.text
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!